# How to change DM group icon using Discord API?

Tags: python, python-requests, discord

I can't change the DM group icon using the Discord API.

I sent a patch request:

```py
import requests

requests.patch(url=f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{group_id}', 
json={'icon': f'data:image/png;base64,{base64_encoded_image}'},
headers={'Authorization': token})
```

and recieved a response (200 code), but DM groups avatar has not changed:

```py
{"id":"<id>", "type":3,
"last_message_id":null, "flags":0,
"recipients":[], "name":null,
"icon":null, "owner_id":"<owner_id>"}
```

I also tried sending the same request with the `User-Agent, Host, Connection, Sec-Fetch-Dest, Sec-Fetch-Mode, Sec-Fetch-Site, X-Super-Properties, Pragma, Cache-Control` headers copied from the browser and got the same response.

Instead of using a bot, I used my Discord user token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing requests using a Discord user token violates Discord's Terms of Service. There is no allowed way of changing a group DM icon via the API.

Comment: If I use a bot token, will I be able to change the group DM icon? The [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#modify-channel) mentions a PATCH request with the option to specify an icon field for the DM group.

Comment: That documentation is for modifying group DMs created by the application via OAuth2; bots cannot manage your personal group DMs.